# Script Tags in Html.Raw()

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't use script tags with Html.Raw() method.

```
<script>
    var content = `@(Html.Raw(Model.content))`;
    //I'll show html content with summernote here
<script>
```

Expected output:

```
<script>
    var content = `<p>bla bla</p><script src="https://example"></script>`; //as string
<script>
```

But I got this:

```
<script>
    var content = `<p>bla bla</p><script src="https://example"></script>`; //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input -> for: </script>
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag is missing. Should be:

```
<script>
    var content = `@(Html.Raw(Model.content))`;       
</script>
```

That exactly what the error description says:

```
Unexpected end of input -> for: </script>
```